# Recursive method for retrieving and concatenating deeply nested arrays from string key

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I'm trying to take an `object` with nested arrays, give them a `string key` and return an array of the concatenated values, so:

Say I have the following data:

```
let data = {
  artists: [{
    name: "Foo",
    concerts: [{
      arena: "Wembley",
      city: "London"
    }, {
      arena: "NEC",
      city: "Birmingham"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Bar",
    concerts: [{
      arena: "Madison Square Garden",
      city: "New York"
    }, {
      arena: "Kodak Theatre",
      city: "Los Angeles"
    }]
  }]
}
```

I want to be able to pass the following string:

`artists.concerts.arena`

And have it return an array of all the values at `arena` for each object, so in this case I want:

```
["Wembly", "NEC", "Madison Square Garden", "Kodak Theatre"]
```

The difficulty I'm having is with the recursive element, I think I'm just not setting and returning the values correctly or I'm calling the recursive element incorrectly, here's the (pretty rough) code:

```
function getValueByStringPath(path, data) {

  path = (Array.isArray(path)) ? path : path.split(".");

  // Loop through the path
  for (var i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
    if (Array.isArray(data)) {
      let vals = [];
      // We have an array, so lets loop through it
      for (var j = 0; j < data.length; j++) {
        // if we have more properties so get them
        if (path.length - 1 > i) {
          vals = getValueByStringPath(path[i + 1], data[j][path[i]])
        } else {
          vals.push(data[j][path[i]]);
        }
      }

      return vals;

    } else {
      data = data[path[i]];
    }
  }

  return (Array.isArray(data)) ? data : [data];
}
```

Here's a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/p0eadu5h/

Comment: What is expected result of `vals = getValueByStringPath(path[i + 1], data[j][path[i]])`?

Comment: @guest271314 This comment actually gave me the answer. Of course I need to concatenate the arrays: `vals = vals.concat(getValueByStringPath(path[i + 1], data[j][path[i]]));` That's a bit nasty, so I'll need to refactor it, but it does the job.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: @guest271314 No probs, I'll add the answer as soon as I get the chance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use nested `for..of` loops to return expected result

```js
let data = {
  artists: [{
    name: "Foo",
    concerts: [{
      arena: "Wembley",
      city: "London"
    }, {
      arena: "NEC",
      city: "Birmingham"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Bar",
    concerts: [{
      arena: "Madison Square Garden",
      city: "New York"
    }, {
      arena: "Kodak Theatre",
      city: "Los Angeles"
    }]
  }]
}

let res = [];
for (let {concerts} of data.artists) {
  for (let {arena} of concerts) {
    res = [...res, arena]
  }
}

console.log(res);
```

Comment: I think the point is a function that can perform this behavior for any path, not just the specific example path. The fact that said behavior is bad practice and should be done with a database or just different data organization is another story

Comment: @Damon that's correct. I do realise that this should be done on the server side, however, this functionality is really intended for quick access to data returned from a public API for prototyping, not production code.

Comment: @craig_h is this how the information is being returned from the API or are you constructing this object? I would thing to separate the data into their own collections rather than nesting them unless they are coming nested from the API.

Comment: @Damon Yes, it's loosely based on the `Spotify API` which presents objects in a similar way, but the code is actually for an open source project, so I have no idea how the data will be presented. I didn't actually intend to implement this, my initial reaction was the same as yours "this should be reformatted on the server side" and I'm still not 100% convinced, but it is difficult to argue with the convenience of  having the ability to do this when API's present information in this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can also chain map reduce on artists array

```js
var data = {
  artists: [{
    name: "Foo",
    concerts: [{
      arena: "Wembley",
      city: "London"
    }, {
      arena: "NEC",
      city: "Birmingham"
    }]
  }, {
    name: "Bar",
    concerts: [{
      arena: "Madison Square Garden",
      city: "New York"
    }, {
      arena: "Kodak Theatre",
      city: "Los Angeles"
    }]
  }]
};
var res = data.artists.map(x => x.concerts).reduce((a,b) => a.concat(b)).map(y => y.arena);
console.log(res);
```